# Sympy: Expanding sum that involves Kets from its quantum module

Tags: python, sympy, quantum-computing

Today I started using sympy and its quantum module to implement some basic calculations in Bra-Ket notation.

Executing the code:

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import *
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import k

print Sum(Ket(k),(k,0,5))
```

yields the expected result, that is, `Sum(|k>, (k, 0, 5))` is printed.

Now I'd like to expand the sum and therefore write:

```
print Sum(Ket(k),(k,0,5)).doit()
```

However, this doesn't give the correct result, but prints out `6*|k>` which obviously is not the desired output. Apparently, the program doesn't recognize `Ket(k)` as depending on the index `k`.

How could I work around or solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. You can probably work around it by doing the sum outside of sympy, with standard python functions like `sum(Ket(i) for i in range(6))`.

Comment: Any workaround, if the limits of k are not known, say, I don't want to take the sum up to 6, but up to an arbitrary number N.